# Add date to table when posting from a form

Tags: php, date

Using a form I am adding some basic fields to my table.

I also want to add the current date the data from the form is posted.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Experiments(Author, Title, Description) 
    VALUES
('$_POST[author]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[description]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection))
    {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
header('Location: http://example.com');
```

Comment: can you be more clear please?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the date that the data was added to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to enter it with PHP. Add a `TIMESTAMP` column to your table and set its default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
ALTER TABLE `Experiments` ADD COLUMN `time` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Oh, and please [sanitize your data entry](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)!

Answer (score 0):

$sql="INSERT INTO Experiments(Author, Title, Description, DATE) 
    VALUES
('$_POST[author]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[description]', NOW())";